# assign statement using virtual interface variable

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I want to connect the module variable to the port in virtual interface using assign statement.

I created one interface and set it as virtual in config_db in my top module. I got the virtual interface via config_db in another module and trying to connect the port in another module to the port in the virtual interface

```
//Below is the sample code

  interface intf();   //Interface

       int values;

  endinterface

  module another_module();   //Another module

       virtual intf u_intf;

       int val;

       assign val = u_intf.values; //I am getting ERROR here

       initial begin
             uvm_config_db#(virtual intf)::get(null,"","assoc_array",u_intf);
       end

  endmodule

  module tb();           // Top TB

       intf u_intf();
       another_module u_another_module();

       initial begin
            uvm_config_db#(virtual intf)::set(uvm_root::get(),"","assoc_array",u_intf);
       end

  endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard does not allow using virtual interfaces in `assign` statements. 
`assign` is used in verilog to connect different RTL blocks. 
`virtual interface` is a system verilog test bench concept.
So, they cannot be mixed together.

You have to clarify, why you really need a `virtual` interface in this contents. They are not synthesizable. Are you writing a test bench module? In general case, you should use regular interfaces to connect modules.

However, in your example you can use `always @*` to do the assignment:

```
always @* val = u_intf.values;
```